# Passing a pointer to an int array to a c-function

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, function, pointers

I have a very basic question.

What is wrong with this call?

```
int params[2] = {1, 1};
return strcmp95((char*)buffer1, (char*)buffer2, (long)stringLength, &params);
```

The function is defined like this:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int *ind_c[])

{...
```

When I compile in XCode, I get the following warning:

> warning: passing argument 4 of
>   'strcmp95' from incompatible pointer
>   type

Sorry for being imprecise. Here is the function description:

> /* Arguments:
>          ying and yang are pointers to the 2 strings to be compared.  The strings
>      need not be NUL-terminated strings
>   because the length is passed.
>          y_length is the length of the strings. 
>          ind_c is an array that is used to define whether certain options should
>   be     activated.  A nonzero value
>   indicates the option is deactivated.
>      The options are:
>        ind_c[0] Increase the probability of a match when the number of matched
>      characters is large.  This option
>   allows for a little more   tolerance
>   when the strings are large.  It is not
>   an appropriate     test when comparing
>   fixed length fields such as phone and
>      social security numbers.
>        ind_c[1] All lower case characters are converted to upper case
>   prior      to the comparison.  Disabling
>   this feature means that the lower
>   case string "code" will not be
>   recognized as the same as the      upper
>   case string "CODE".  Also, the
>   adjustment for similar     characters
>   section only applies to uppercase
>   characters.
>          The suggested values are all zeros for character strings such as
>   names.    */

Comment: Are you saying this doesn't compile elsewhere? Ie this is xcode specific?

Comment: I didn't know, that is why I added the tag. Could have been something was missing in XCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` is an `int [2]`, which decays to an `int *` when passed to a function, and functions that take `int []`s as parameters are really taking `int *`s behind the scenes. Unfortunately, `&params` is an `int(*)[2]`, which is closer to an `int *` than the `int **` (same as `int *[]` in a function parameter) you need.

Your best option is to change your function to:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int *ind_c)
```

And assume that the caller willl always pass an `int[2]`. Or you can explicitly ask for an `int(*)[2]` - a pointer to an array of 2 `int`s:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int (*ind_c)[2])
```

But this seems unnecessary to guarantee that two `int`s are passed, and if you need to account for the possibility of more than two `int`s in the array is unsuitable. A better way is:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int *ind_c, size_t len)
```

`size_t` is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to be able to hold the size of any object or any array index, and in this case the `len` parameter is the length of your array (`(sizeof params / sizeof params[0])` if you want to be fancy/forward thinking, `2` if you don't). That's the safest route.

By the way, your `y_length` parameter should also be a `size_t` variable. `long` is signed, and I'd hate to have to handle a string of -1 length. Even if you use `unsigned long`, there's no guarantee that `long` will be sufficient to handle a system's sizes (or, conversely, that an errantly large `long` value will be too big for your system to handle and cause confusion).

Comment: No, `&params` is not the same as `params`. The addresses that they hold are the same but `&params` has type `int (*)[2]`.

Comment: I opted for int (*ind_c)[2]. The function is only ever gonna get called by myself, and only in one place. That is never gonna change. So that option seems very safe in this scenario.

Comment: @Jens - This is what happens when you stay up until 5 a.m. after saying "I'm going to go to bed early tonight and wake up at a reasonable hour." Fixing.

Comment: @Joseph - If you only call it in one place and have such specific array requirements, why is it a separate function?

Comment: It is a function that was written in 1994. And not by myself. I am only using it. :)

Comment: Wow. I was 4 when somebody wrote that. They had no idea some 4-year-old would grow up and answer a question about their code from his cell phone. Personally, I'd make the two `int` values in the array separate `int` parameters so that the function caller doesn't have to declare a temporary array just to call it.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp95` takes a pointer to pointer to int (`int **`), while you are passing it a pointer to an array of two ints (`int (*)[2]`).

You could modify `strcmp95` so that its signature looks like this:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int (*ind_c)[] );
```

The point here is that a pointer to an array (`int (*x)[]`) is not the same as an array of pointers (which is `int *(x[])` and is the same as `int *x[]`)

Comment: Uhm... okay. I'll try and figure out how to change that. :) What are the advantages / disadvantages of either approach?

Comment: @Joseph Tura: I updated the answer. `int *x[]` is an array of pointers, while you are passing a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know whether strcmp95 should take an array of ints like you're trying to pass, or it is meant to take an array of int pointers as the prototype requests.  The former seems likely - if so, you should change...

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int *ind_c[])
```

...to...

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int *ind_c)
```

...or, equivalently...

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int ind_c[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing &params, params would be suffice, as an array acts like a pointer.

```
return strcmp95((char*)buffer1, (char*)buffer2, (long)stringLength, params);
```

And secondly strcmp95 should now be expecting an array of ints, this will be fine:

```
double  strcmp95(char *ying, char *yang, long y_length, int ind_c[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Also I think you are passing params ( which is an integer pointer in itself ) and the function strncmp95 is expecting pointer to an array of integers i.e int *ind_c[].